# printdocument prints too many pages

Tags: c#, printdocument

Help, I have a problem where PrintDocument is printing too many pages for no obvious reason

Unfortunately the error is a bit difficult to reproduce. I have never been able to reproduce it during testing. It only happens when users are printing documents of more than two pages.
The documents to be print are multipage Tiff images

I have the following code in my print window:

```
PrintDocumentAdvanced p = new PrintDocumentAdvanced(tmpFileName);

p.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Prt-002";
p.PreparePrint();
p.Print();
```

The PreparePrint method is setting what pages should be print. It reads the number of pages in the tiff file:

```
PreparePrint()
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(tmp);
    Guid objGuid = img.FrameDimensionsList[0];
    FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
    int cnt = img.GetFrameCount(objDimension);
    PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
    PrinterSettings.ToPage = cnt;
}
```

When printing it will call this for each page:

```
private void PreparePrint(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(tmp);
    Guid objGuid = img.FrameDimensionsList[0];
    FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);

    // Checks if there are more pages to be printed

    Logger("Trying to print page " + lastPagePrinted + " Total pages: " + img.GetFrameCount(objDimension));

    if (img.GetFrameCount(objDimension) > lastPagePrinted + 1 && lastPagePrinted + 1 < PrinterSettings.ToPage)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }

    Logger("Has more pages: " + e.HasMorePages);

    img.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, lastPagePrinted);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);
}
```

As you can see in the code, I have added two loggers. The result when printing a three page document:

> Trying to print page 0 Total pages: 3
>
> Has more pages: True
>
> Trying to print page 1 Total pages: 3
>
> Has more pages: True
>
> Trying to print page 2 Total pages: 3
>
> Has more pages: False
>
> Trying to print page 3 Total pages: 3
>
> Has more pages: False

When printing page 3 (page with index 2) it sees there are no more pages to be print and we have also reached the last page to be printed on the Settings.ToPage, but still it decides to call the print method one more time which of course will fail as there are no more pages in the document
This does not happen every time something is printed. All documents of 1 page will print correctly, but with more than 1 page there is a ~50% chance it will fail

Any idea why?

I have been searching for this problem a lot, but so far haven't been able to find anything.
I have also tried to change the code, where PrinterSettings.FromPage and PrinterSettings.ToPage will not be used, but have my own variables to keep track on what pages needs to be print, but it made no difference

The code for the full class (with a few changes compared to above code):

```
public class PrintDocumentAdvanced : PrintDocument
    {
        private string tmp = "tmpPrint.tif";
        private string fileName;

        public PrintDocumentAdvanced(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.PrintPage += PreparePrint;
        }

        private int firstPage;
        private int lastPage;

        private bool printPrepared = false;

        public bool PreparePrint()
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                FileTools.Converter.ConvertPdfToTiff(fileName, tmp);

                Image img = Image.FromFile(tmp);
                Guid objGuid = img.FrameDimensionsList[0];
                FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);

                // Checks if there are more pages to print

                int cnt = img.GetFrameCount(objDimension);

                if (PrinterSettings.FromPage > PrinterSettings.ToPage)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (PrinterSettings.FromPage == 0 && PrinterSettings.ToPage == 0)
                {
                    firstPage = 1;
                    lastPage = cnt;
                    PrinterSettings.FromPage = 0;
                    PrinterSettings.ToPage = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstPage = PrinterSettings.FromPage;
                    lastPage = PrinterSettings.ToPage;
                    PrinterSettings.FromPage = 0;
                    PrinterSettings.ToPage = 0;
                }

                lastPagePrinted = firstPage - 1;

                img.Dispose();
                img = null;

                printPrepared = true;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                printPrepared = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void DisposeObject()
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(tmp);
        }

        private int lastPagePrinted = -1;

        private void PreparePrint(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (printPrepared == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("PreparePrint() needs to be called before printing!");
            }

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                // Loads tif file from image

                Image img = Image.FromFile(tmp);

                Guid objGuid = img.FrameDimensionsList[0];

                FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);

                // Checks if there are more pages to print
                Logger("Trying to print page " + lastPagePrinted + " Total pages: " + img.GetFrameCount(objDimension));

                if (img.GetFrameCount(objDimension) > lastPagePrinted + 1 && lastPagePrinted + 1 < lastPage)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                }

                Logger("Has more pages: " + e.HasMorePages);

                img.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, lastPagePrinted);

                Rectangle m = new Rectangle(-25, -25, e.PageBounds.Width /*+ e.PageBounds.X - (e.PageSettings.Margins.Right / 2)*/, e.PageBounds.Height /*+ e.PageBounds.Y - (e.PageSettings.Margins.Bottom / 2)*/);

                if ((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
                {
                    m.Height = (int)((double)img.Height / (double)img.Width * (double)m.Width);
                }
                else
                {
                    m.Width = (int)((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height * (double)m.Height);
                }

                // Draws the image to the print object

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);

                // Disposes the temporary image and delete the file

                img.Dispose();

                lastPagePrinted++;
            }
        }

        public void Logger(String lines)
        {

            // Write the string to a file.append mode is enabled so that the log
            // lines get appended to  test.txt than wiping content and writing the log

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Temp\\mylog.txt", true);
            file.WriteLine(lines);

            file.Close();

        }
    }
```

Extra note: The full code actually receives a string with the path to a .PDF file. It will then convert the .PDF file to a .TIF file, which it will read and print

Comment: Crystal ball says that you subscribed your PrintPage event handler more than once.

Comment: Where do you increment the lastPagePrinted variable?  Is there another print method being used? because the PreparePrint looks like it always uses the initial image settings.  Is PrintDocumentAdvanced your own inherited class?  Document that.  It's hard to help if you don't provide us code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant - I didn't subscribe to the PrintPage event handler. I assume when I call p.Print(); it does it automatically?

Comment: @LarsTech - PrintDocumentAdvanced is my own code. I have added the full code for the class in the initial post. As I mentioned earlier, it is unfortunately difficult to duplicate the problem as I e.g. can print the same document 5 times, where it fails 2 of the times

Comment: You definitely subscribe the PrintPage event, you do so in the constructor.  Naming the event handler "PreparePrint" is very misleading.   Proper way to do it is to override OnPagePrint() instead.  Likewise, the public PreparePrint should be on override for OnBeginPrint() instead and not be called explicitly.  Whether that helps you discover the bug is however not that obvious.  This code is confusing you too much, probably best to just throw it away and use a regular PrintDocument.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks, this gave me the idea on how to fix the problem (at least since I made the last changes it hasn't caused me any problems, but still needs more testing). I'm still not sure what caused the problem in the first place. What I did was overriding OnBeginPrint() And OnPrintPage() and remove the weirdly named methods I had before. All the code from my two methods is now inside the overridden methods and I removed the code where I subscribed to PrintPage. Thanks for the help :)